# Calculating work to move a particle

Tags: energy, particle-physics

I have this question : There is a negatively charged spherical shell. Within this shell is a positive charge q which is at the center of the shell. How much work is required to move the charge from the middle to a position where the particle is right next to the inside wall of the shell.

The answer is 0 but I don't know how to get that. I understand work is the change in potential energy and in this case that would just be $ {kqq\over r^2} $ so wouldn't work just be the potential energy at the center minus the potential energy after the change in position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric field due to the negatively charged shell is zero inside due to symmetry.
There is no field inside ,so force on the particle will be zero and since force is zero you don't need to push the particle against electric field to bring the particle from the middle to a position where the particle is right next to the inside wall of the shell.
So work done on the particle must be zero.